# Reference Request: Brownian motion on Riemannian manifolds

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, brownian-motion

Can you recommend any classical literature concerning Brownian motion on Riemannian manifolds?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I like stochastic analysis on manifolds by Elton P. Hsu.

Comment: Stroock *An Introduction to the Analysis of Paths on a Riemannian Manifold*.

Comment: Wang *Analysis for Diffusion Processes on Riemanian Manifolds*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brownian motion on a Riemannian manifold can be written as an Ito diffusion dependent on the metric.

From Ito himself: [The Brownian Motion and Tensor Fields on Riemannian Manifold](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/118e/45e3441c94175b003245b1ec1ab4ce4bd287.pdf), [Stochastic Differential Equations in a Differentiable Manifold](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.nmj/1118764702), [Stochastic Differential Equations in a Differentiable Manifold (2)](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.kjm/1250777513).

Since the heat kernel is essentially the transition density function of Brownian motion, there are deep connections to the heat equation on the manifold, as well as the Laplace-Beltrami operator.

See [Hsu, Stochastic Analysis on Manifolds](https://books.google.ca/books?hl=en&lr=&id=GDEPCgAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PP1&dq=hsu+riemannian+manifold&ots=mrM118KN3H&sig=hIUsd9_LfDBHMZQaEJ9G7lkWOLU#v=onepage&q=hsu%20riemannian%20manifold&f=false) and [Grigoryan, Heat Kernel and Analysis on Manifolds](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~grigor/btopmatter.pdf). A more in-depth analysis is in [Ikeda, Stochastic differential equations and diffusion processes](https://books.google.ca/books?hl=en&lr=&id=QZbOBQAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PP1&dq=ikeda+diffusion+processes&ots=rZXoF8u5HW&sig=4uwn6w53ZcPG8dp9EbzIPl_UNTg#v=onepage&q=ikeda%20diffusion%20processes&f=false). These have plenty of references at which to look as well.

There also some interesting recent work, from more applied perspectives. Here's a couple: [1](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3215/222470768a73cd3b7d2fe89a9496d5518a5e.pdf), [2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.03679.pdf), [3](http://www.cim.mcgill.ca/~shape/publications/cgf2017.pdf), and [4](http://www.numdam.org/article/AIF_1984__34_2_243_0.pdf).